# I want to know minimum x value 10**x > 2**2048 w/ python

Tags: python

I want to know minimum x value `10**x > 2**2048` w/ python
I think `10**i` is bigger than `2**2048`, so what I want to know is number 'i'
but my code has overflow so I can not solve this problem

```
two = 2
ten = 10
i=1
print(two)
print(ten)
while two <= 2**2048:
    two = two*2
while ten <= two:
    ten = ten*10
ten = ten*10
while ten > 10:
    ten = ten/10
    i += 1
print('10**',i)
```

solve my problem
I want to know minimum x value 10**x > 2**2048 w/ python

Comment: Your first loop is silly.  Just set `two = 2**2048`.  The answer to your question is `math.log(2)*2048/math.log(10)` rounded up.

Comment: Do you understand why you get an overflow?  Python has infinitely long integers, but floats are limited.  Your code stays with integers until you do `ten = ten/10`, which is a floating point division.  At that point, `ten` is larger than the largest floating point value.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you really don't want to use the correct method, which is logarithms, here's the iterative solution:

```
count = 0
ten = 1
two = 2**2048
while ten < two:
    count += 1
    ten *= 10
print(count)
```

Comment: Also assuming that they don't want to do this, there is always the length method since he is just using 10**x. `print(len(str(2**2048)))`

Answer (score -2):

```
import math

result = math.log(2**2048+1, 10)

if int(result)!=result:
    result=int(result)+1
print(result)
```

Sure, let's break down the code step by step and explain each part:

1. `import math`: This line imports the math module, which provides various mathematical functions and constants.
2. `result = math.log(2**2048+1, 10)`: Here, we calculate the logarithm base 10 of the number `2**2048+1`. The expression `2**2048` represents 2 raised to the power of 2048. The `+1` is added to ensure that the logarithm result will be greater than the logarithm of `2**2048`, as required by the problem.
3. `if int(result)!=result:`: This condition checks if the result of the logarithm calculation is not an integer, meaning it has a fractional part.
4. `result=int(result)+1`: If the result is not an integer, this line converts the result to an integer using `int()` and then adds 1 to the integer value. The purpose of adding 1 is to ensure that we find the minimum integer value that satisfies the condition `10**x > 2**2048`.
5. `print(result)`: Finally, the code prints the calculated result, which represents the minimum value of `x` that satisfies the inequality `10**x > 2**2048`.

Explanation of the problem:
The problem statement asks us to find the minimum value of `x` such that `10**x > 2**2048`. In other words, we need to find the smallest integer `x` that makes 10 raised to the power of `x` greater than 2 raised to the power of 2048.

Since both 10 and 2 are positive numbers, their powers will keep increasing as `x` increases. So, the minimum value of `x` that satisfies the inequality will be an integer greater than the logarithm base 10 of `2**2048` (which is `2048`) by at least 1. Hence, we need to calculate the logarithm of `2**2048+1` base 10 and round it up to the next integer to find the minimum value of `x`.

Keep in mind that large exponentiations like `2**2048` can result in extremely large numbers, so the code uses logarithms to simplify the calculation and find the result efficiently.

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT